# Can XIP (execute in place) be used for kernel protection?

Tags: memory, kernel

Starting with kernel 5.13 RiscV will get XIP where parts of the kernel run from non volatile memory like flash. In theory you could make parts of the kernel really read only either from the hardware side by storing on a write protected chip or a bit limited write protection via the hypervisor when run in a VM. Will  this be useful to thwart any memory related attacks? And can this be extended to other binaries?

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=RISC-V-XIP-For-Linux-5.13

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/riscv/linux.git/commit/?h=for-next&id=06c7c914de26c5a4f1418fd54e4dfd0be4215de6